# React "TypeError: imageCollection.map" is not a function only after state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

So I am building a little app to practice my skills and im grabbing images from the pixabay API.

I want to be able to search images and automatically update when the user clicks the search button

On load the code loads some of the images

```
const [imageCollection, setImageCollection] = useState();
const searchTerm = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
    if (!imageCollection) {
        let images = [];
        Axios.get('https://pixabay.com/api/?key=x=yellow+flowers&image_type=photo&per_page=10')
             .then(res => {
                 res.data.hits.map(img => {
                     images.push(img.largeImageURL);
                 })
             });
        setImageCollection(images);
    }
}, []);
```

Then I have a search bar that when you click on search it updates the state

```
const handleSearch = () => {
    let string = encodeURI(searchTerm.current.value).replace('%20', '+');
    let new_images = [];
    Axios.get('https://pixabay.com/api/?key=x=' + string + '&image_type=photo&per_page=10')
         .then(res => {
             res.data.hits.map(img => {
                 new_images.push(img.largeImageURL);
             })
         });

    setImageCollection(...imageCollection, new_images);
}
```

This is how I am printing out the images

```
{
    imageCollection 
        ? imageCollection.map(img => {
            return <Image link={img}/>
          }) 
        : ""
}
```

I get an error after I hit search, it loads fine before.

> TypeError: imageCollection.map is not a function error

Comment: Is  imageCollection an array?

Comment: Yeah it is, i did have that error @aleksey pointed out

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake here

```
setImageCollection(...imageCollection, new_images);
```

it should be like this

```
setImageCollection([...imageCollection, ...new_images]);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. The error is gone but the state doesn't update, I've checked the state and it doesn't update, i've console logged the array and theres definitely images in there..